# mysql - select groups of rows by count?

Tags: mysql

Given a table showing awards earned by members of an organization, I am trying to list all the members who earned three or more awards after a given date, and to list all of the awards earned by those members.  I have a query that will correctly list the members, but it shows only one row per member, and I'm trying to see all of their awards.

There is one row in the table for each award ("Award") earned by any member, with the award type and the date it was earned ("Awarddate").

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT Membername, Award, Awarddate,COUNT(Membername) 
FROM awards 
WHERE Awarddate > '2011-06-30' 
GROUP BY Membername HAVING COUNT(Membername) > 2
```

Suggestions?

Comment: What's the unique identifier for your table? is it a combination of member name, awarddate and award? or is there a separate ID?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function:

```
SELECT Membername
     , COUNT(*)                                    AS NumberOfAwards
     , GROUP_CONCAT(Award ORDER BY Awarddate)      AS Awards
     , GROUP_CONCAT(Awarddate ORDER BY Awarddate)  AS AwardDates
FROM awards 
WHERE Awarddate > '2011-06-30' 
GROUP BY Membername 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: Very nice, and shows all awards on one line.  But supposing I wanted to retain the "one award per row" format so users could see the date of each award.  What would that look like?

Comment: If you want them in one row per award, you can use @piotrm's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.Membername, a.Award, a.Awarddate, Awardcount.Awards
FROM awards a
JOIN
  ( SELECT Membername, COUNT(*) AS Awards
    FROM awards
    WHERE Awarddate > '2011-06-30' 
    GROUP BY Membername 
    HAVING Awards > 2 ) Awardcount
ON a.Membername = Awardcount.Membername
```

Edit: to list only awards earned after given date add one more line to this query as suggested by ypercube:

```
WHERE a.Awarddate > '2011-06-30'
```

Comment: I think you also need `WHERE a.Awarddate > '2011-06-30'` in the external query.

Comment: I ran that query, and it works, except that the WHERE clause isn't working - it is showing all awards, including those earlier than 2011-06-30.  What could be causing that?

Oops, just saw ypercube's response - that does it.  Wonderful, thanks!